# Use arcpy.SearchCursor with raster

Tags: python, arcpy

How can I efficiently subdivide one raster into multiple rasters using the arcpy.SearchCursor?

For example if I have a  slope and I was to subdivide into 3 rasters:

```
slope1 with values between 0 and 25degress

slope2 with values between 25 and 50degress

slope3 with values > 50degress
```

Here I should easily solve the problem with **arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters**

If for example i have one categorical file and I also want to do the same thing?
If the file I have has only one field with the identification of the category and it's a string.

```
Value    Count    Type
    1    1023     Protected Area 2000
    2    1000     Protected Area 2001
    3    9555     Protected Area 2002
    4    9500     Protected Area 2003
    5    200     Construction Site
    6    (...)    (...)
```

Should I use **arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters**?

Furthermore, if I want to aggregate certain categories in only one raster, other groups of categories in other rasters?

When using the **Search Cursor** we are doing the changes directly to the source file ?should I create a copy for each raster I want to produce?

Comment: Just for clarification, SearchCursor by itself doesn't modify your original attribute table.  InsertCursor and UpdateCursor do.  SearchCursor is basically a read-only data access object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the Spatial Analyst extension, you can use [ExtractByAttributes](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z00000029000000.htm) or [Raster Calculator](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000z7000000.htm) to create your three rasters.  Both of these tools can be called up in Python and are simpler (IMHO) solutions to using cursors.